How to correctly pass a template parameter pack to another variadic template
The result of the following code I think should print "FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1 A&& ", but it doesn't。And it reported an error。
"Error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol 'public: void* __cdecl A::dispatch<0, int, class A>(int, class A)' (??dispatch@dispatch@0A@HVA@@@A@@QEAAPEAXHV0@@Z)"
#include <iostream>
enum class FUNC_TYPE {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
};
class A {
public:
    template<FUNC_TYPE type, typename... T>
    static void* __dispatch(A* a, T&& ...t) {
        return a->dispatch<type,T...>(std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }

    template<FUNC_TYPE tag, typename... T>
    void* dispatch(T... t);
};
template<>
void* A::dispatch<FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1>(int i, A&& a) {
    std::cout << "FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1 A&& " << i << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}
template<>
void* A::dispatch<FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1>(int i, A& a) {
    std::cout << "FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1 A& " << i << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}
A get() {
    return A();
}
int main() {
    A a;
    A::__dispatch<FUNC_TYPE::TYPE1>(&a, 1, get());
}

What changes need to be made to ensure it works correctly?
And this is C++. Which concept does this pertain to? Are there any recommended materials for further reading?

The parameter pack T in your example is {int, A}, not {int, A&&}. So it tries to call an instaniation of A::dispatch for which you didn't provide an implementation.

Yes, but how should __dispatch be modified to pass {int, A&&} to the A::dispatch method?

You can't - at least, not generically. You want an rvalue to be passed by value for the first parameter (int), but as rvalue reference for the second parameter (A). In other words, you want to transform parameter pack {int, A} into {int, A&&} and not {int&&, A&&}. Why do you want this asymmetry? How do you decide which parameter is to be passed by value and which by reference? What actual problem are you trying to solve?
